# How to properly use CASE WHEN / THEN / ELSE with IN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE tbl_pedidos_produtos SET status = CASE 
    WHEN id IN (SELECT produto_id FROM tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos) THEN 4
    ELSE 3 END WHERE pedido_id = ".$produto->itens[$t]->pedido_id
```

Is this "WHEN id IN (...)" valid? How can I do such a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid way do an update.

You can do testing with SQLFiddle like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67b3a/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5158af/1

```
create table test (id int, status varchar(10));
insert into test values (1, null);

create table test2 (id int);
insert into test2 values (2);

update test
set status = case when id in (select id from test2) then 4 else 3 end
where id = 1;

select * from test
```

Result:

```
| id | status |
|----|--------|
|  1 |      3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `left join` clause in your update statement should do the trick:

```
UPDATE    tbl_pedidos_produtos pp
LEFT JOIN tbl_pedidos_cotacaos_produtos pcp ON pp.id = pcp.produto_id
SET       pp.status = CASE WHEN pcp.produto_id IS NULL THEN 4 ELSE 3 END
WHERE     pedido_id = ".$produto->itens[$t]->pedido_id
```